# How to restrict Apache to internal traffic

Tags: apache

I need to make sure that there is no chance that my Apache server cannot be accessed by external users, or users on the same network. I installed it via the installer from wampserver, and I'm not intimately familiar with the configuration.

Comment: "external users, even on the same network" - I understood your question right until that point. What are you defining as internal/external users and traffic? Sounds like you need a username and password and not IP based restrictions.

Comment: I rephrased it, as that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want Apache to listen on localhost/loopback only. You can either set up a rule in Windows firewall to do this (i.e. set up port blocking rules for 80, 443, and whatever other ports your Apache is listening on), or you can define a Listen directive in the Apache configuration, e.g. Listen 127.0.0.1:80.